# drf mongoengine serializer imagefield none

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, django-serializer

I used Django restframework and mongoengine.

Here is my model and serializer.

[model.py]

```
class Attachment(EmbeddedDocument):
    attachment_id = SequenceField()
    path = StringField()
    path_small = StringField()

class Book(Document):
    book_id = SequenceField()
    user_id = LongField(required=True)
    attachments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Attachment))
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
```

[serializer.py]

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer
from rest_framework.serializers import ImageField
from books.models.mongo import Book

class BookSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    image = ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Appeal
        fields = (
            'book_id',
            'image',
        )
```

Work flow like this.

1. Upload image to s3
2. Get s3 path
3. Save s3 path to `attachments` field in models.py.

So do not defined attachments to `ImageField()` in models.py.

Just set `image = ImageField()` in serializer to validate it is correct image.

But when I validate with `serializer.is_valid()`, image get `None`.

[views.py]

```
class BookList(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = ''

    def post(self, request: Request) -> Union[Response, NoReturn]:
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.data)
            appeal = CreateAppealInteractor().execute(request=serializer.data)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

As you know that after `serializer.is_valid()`, I printed serializer.data.

But it throw None like this -> `{'book_id': 1, 'image': None}`

Is there any error in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `Book` class have `image` field or property? If not, `ImageField` on `BookSerializer` becomes a `None` value or causes an error because there is nothing to refer to.

Comment: @YongjinJo No. `Book` class do not have `image` filed. Because I just want to validate user input via serializer. So I defined `image = ImageField()` in `serializers.py`.

Comment: I understand. But in your view, you are using `AppealSerializer` not `BookSerializer` to set `request.data`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @YongjinJo Sorry, while copy code, I insert wrong code. But in my work code is `BookSerializer`. Can we talk on chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188373/drfdrf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved in chat room. Just use `validated_data`.

```
class BookList(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = ''

    def post(self, request: Request) -> Union[Response, NoReturn]:
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            appeal = CreateAppealInteractor().execute(request=serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```